# Laravel 4.2: not able to log out user

Tags: laravel

I am trying to logout the user:

```
public  function getSignOut() {

        Auth::logout();

        return Redirect::to('/');


}
```

However, when it hits this route:

```
Route::get('/', function()
   {

     if(Auth::check()){

        return 'logged in';
   }else {

     return 'not logged in';
  }

});
```

It returns that the user is still logged in. What could be the problem and thanks in advance for helping fix the problem.

Comment: any fancy route filters? like `Route::filter('auth.basic', ...`?

Comment: Too little info here. What url do you run do logout user? What are your routes? Are you sure `getSignOut` is being launched at all?

Comment: How do you call the logout function? Is it set to a route?